# Configure juju on Rackspace

Tags: juju, cloud

I want to deploy a successfull juju env on rackspace infrastructure, i follow all the steps in the official doc, i google but nothing reveal. There is any other step or configuration i miss?

I'm having trouble finding information about how to bootstrap and orchestrate a rackspace based environment. I've followed all the official documentation with an Openstack provider, but this doesn't seem to work.

Are there any further configuration steps I have missed? Perhaps a provider that's being written that I do not have?

Answer (score 4):

Rackspace clouds are directly supported by Juju 2.0+

For information about adding credentials, see:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/help-rackspace

Comment: As an addendum to this answer - currently (as of early 2015) there are missing bits from rackspace's openstack infrastructure that juju relies on. So the manual provider at present is your best bet.

Comment: I was just at a Rackspace Solve event last week and was in a DevOps demo. The had a system called 'CheckMate' that looks eerily like JuJu Charms. The Dev Ops engineer said it was internal only so far though.

Comment: updated answer now there is Rackspace support in 2.0